# Set Current Branch

Tags: git, branch, reset

I did two git commit and git push to a branch `MyBranch` that I needed to revert. Based on some google search I did the following while being on branch `MyBranch`:

```
git reset [shaNumber]
[do some changes]
git commit -m"my comments"
git push -f
```

Then I did a complete new git clone and git checkout to get to `MyBranch`. However, I don't seem to be on the current branch anymore because when I use TortoiseGit (I only use it to look at logs and visual graphs) I don't see the red part anymore. I only see the brown/yellowish area. I am afraid that if I make further changes I could mess up the repository so how do I get that red part back again?

As it should be:
[image: As it should be]

Answer (score 0):

To switch to a branch is `git checkout *name of branch*`

```
git add .
git commit -m "commit"
git push
```

Those three commands will push code from your local repo to the remote. I can't tell from your explanation if you completed these steps before doing a fresh git clone (which you should try to avoid in the future imjo).

Also, `git log` is your friend here, you can see all the commits by time/branch.

Comment: You might be up to something. I just realized that I didn't actually add my changes but just did the following items below. So are you saying if I actually do a git add, git commit and git push -f then I will get back that red box? I don't want to try it and mess something up: git push -f
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To http://[IPAddress]/[Project].git/
 + 2d6120e6...4b2a411 [branch] -> [branch] (forced update)

Comment: Check the code directly instead of the graph, you can check out commits directly by using the SHA number